# Mapping Tables of Database in NiFi

Tags: database, mapping, lookup, apache-nifi

Here is my requirement. 
I have a big table in Vertica say base_table as follows.
base_table

ID |   path    |   service  |  experience

20 |  /abc/xyz  |   trz    |    moderate
22 |  /wer/cmz  |   brd    |  professional

---

Mapping Tables

map_table1

path_id | path

1       | /abc/xyz

---

map_table2

exp_id | experience

1   |      beginner

---

Final Table

ID | path_id | service |  exp_id

20 | 1       | trz     | -

22 | -       | brd     | 2

---

In the First case, I need to get ID as 1 as the path column is present in the map_table1 as well as base table and insert that record into the final table.

In the Second case, I need to insert id as 2 in map_table2 as experience professional is not present in that table as well as insert it into the final table.

which processors should I go for or how the flow should look like in Nifi?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad, fulfilling this story would likely require multiple steps and tools.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I generalize the situation, you want to insert a record if it does not exist, and then get the value of the corresponding ID (which may or may not have existed before).

The good news is that NiFi can easily work with a database like Vertica, have a look at the [QueryDatabaseTable](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html) processor.

The challenge here however, is that NiFi is designed to efficiently handle many individual messages, and is therefore designed not to be very context aware. For your usecase you would probably want to use a tool that is built to work with tables. In general the solution for this would be [Spark](https://www.cloudera.com/products/open-source/apache-hadoop/apache-spark.html), or perhaps it can be built into your database with some procedures.